# Error converting value {null} to type 'System.DateTime' in input json

Tags: c#, json, datetime, null, deserialization

This JsonSerializationException was thrown when I tried to input the following DateTime parameters in my Json :

> "Error converting value {null} to type 'System.DateTime' in input json"

I have given the input here :

```
string inputJSONString = "{....,\"StartDateFrom\":null,\"StartDateTo\":null,\"EndDateFrom\":null,\"EndDateTo\":null,\....}";
```

and deserialising using :

```
scT = (SearchCriteriaTask)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(inputJSONString , typeof(SearchCriteriaTask));
```

My json is correct , and I have also tried ("") values instead of null. 
I was not able to find proper solution elsewhere. Thanks.

If any part of code is needed, then please mention it.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, .Net value types like `DateTime` cannot hold nulls.

If you want to allow nulls, use nullable types:

```
DateTime? StartDateFrom { get; set; }
```

Comment: I now have come to know about how basic this problem was ! i had no idea it used a nullable like this. I am very new to it. this worked. Thanks

Comment: If someone has the question as to why DateTime can't be null, that answer can be found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689512/why-is-null-not-allowed-for-datetime-in-c