# null date in json gives error in rest call

Tags: c#, json, rest

We are retrieving a block of cities and one of them has a null date in a field which generates an exception.  How can I intercept the error but still get large blocks of records. We didn't want to retrieve the records 1 at a time as we have several thousand records to get.

> Error converting value {null} to type 'System.DateTime'. Path 'result.records[0].datelec', line 1, position 4360. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

```
RootObject test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(fileMunicipalities);
            municipalities.AddRange(test.result.Records);
            urlService = URL_BASE +test.result._links.next;
        }
        while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(urlService));
        string t = "";
```

Comment: What's the definition of `RootObject`? Or rather, what's the definition of the object whose property is typed `DateTime`?

Comment: You'll have to make that property a nullable DateTime if it's possible for the value to be null.

Comment: Indeed, as shown in [Error converting value {null} to type 'System.DateTime' in input json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18534429/3744182).

Comment: Or if you **really** don't want to change your data model, you could use `NullToDefaultConverter<DateTime>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31750851/3744182) to [Json.net deserialization null guid case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31747712/3744182).  The converter works for any struct, and replaces the null value with a default value, here `default(DateTime)`.

Comment: OK added a ? to allow nulls as per heritic monkey!                                        public DateTime? datelec { get; set; }