# I can't use datetime subtract method

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I can't use following Datetime subtract method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.datetime.subtract(v=vs.110).aspx

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Proffesional 2013 and VisualBasic2013 and .NetFrameWork Version 4.5.50938

I want to use above method. I can use Add method like this:

```
Dim dt As Datetime = Nothing
dt.Add(New TimeSpan(1))
```

I want to know why although there is the homepage that is Datetime.
Subtract, I can't use subtract method......

Comment: Show the code that you have tried and explain the issue

Comment: Please add your code and put it between [code] tags, explained in the formatting help. And tell us exactly what happened, and what you expected to happen.

Comment: thank you for replying.
And sorry , I have solved the problem by myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see what happens when you try to create a DateTime as Nothing:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = Nothing
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff"))
```

we get "0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000". This is the earliest datetime that can be represented by a DateTime. It can't hold a "value" of `Nothing` because it is a Value type: [Why is null not allowed for DateTime in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/689518/1115360).

Let's try adding 1 tick:

```
dt.Add(New TimeSpan(1))
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff"))
```

Oh! We get "0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000" again. The tick was not added on. That is because the `Add` method returns a new DateTime - it does not affect the one that `Add` was invoked on.

Let's try again:

```
dt = dt.Add(New TimeSpan(1))
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff"))
```

Now we get "0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000001", as intended.

What happens if we try to go earlier than the first allowed DateTime?

```
Dim dt As DateTime = Nothing
dt = dt.Subtract(New TimeSpan(1))
```

It throws a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: Just a heads up: some users may find the tone of this answer a bit too flippant. Personally I have little issue with it, but others seem to think differently.